# Recommended approach to test iOS app against beta iOS releases

Tags: iphone, ios, compatibility, beta-testing, release-cycle

It is good to be able to test apps against beta releases of iOS, but the number of beta releases Apple is pushing out seems to turn the benevolence into annoyance for me on several bases:

- huge file downloads for the SDK and iOS images
- having to keep fixing things, which may be broken in the next beta
- the release notes from Apple is often not enough for me to figure out why my apps break
- the NDA makes it much more difficult to find an answer on the Web

So, I started wondering, how other iOS developers deal with this. Does Apple have a recommended approach to test apps with their frequent beta releases? When should I submit the fixes to Apple for the new iOS (keeping in mind that it might be broken in the next beta relesae)?

Could someone please suggest or point me to a plausible approach to test apps against beta iOS releases?

Comment: I'd suggest moving this post to the Apple Developer forums because of the very same NDA you mention in your post.

Comment: @James, this is not the first time Apple does several beta releases, and this question is meant to be a general one, not just for iOS 5. How can it violate the DNA?

Comment: Had to delete my comment too! It breached!

Answer (score 2):

Once a GM version of the OS and SDK is out, you have at least a week before it goes public. This should be enough to fix any iOS version-related bugs, submit the update and get it accepted. If you are afraid it will not be ready before public release of the OS, you can request an expedited review and state that app breaks on new OS as a reason.

As for things that can go wrong with beta OS versions, it's too general to discuss, and we can't discuss particular iOS 5 problems here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please give me a pointer to your comment regarding GM release, that it's one week before the SDK goes public?

Comment: Every release of iOS that had developer beta so far had a GM released to developers one to two weeks before the public release, so I'm guessing it will be the same with iOS 5.